# How to download an image with PHP?

Tags: php, image

Suppose the url of the image is here:

http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png

How to download it with PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen('logo.png', 'w');
fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png'));
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would a plain [`file_get_contents`](http://us.php.net/file_get_contents) and [`file_put_contents`](http://us.php.net/file_put_contents) would do it

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png')
file_put_contents('logo.png', $content);
```

have to be noted that with that way of doing the whole file will be stocked in memory, so you have to be careful about the `memory_limit`. If you need a method without puting the file in memory [curl](http://us.php.net/curl) would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a curl request :

```
public static function curlGet($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $content = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $content;
}
```

and write the content response into a file

```
$fp = fopen('logo.png', 'w');
fwrite($fp, curlGet('http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png') );
fclose($fp);
```