# Uploading an image which is within <img> tag to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, file-upload

Can I upload an image to my web server. I know that, If I have file input in my web page, then I can easily upload it and get it like `$_FILE["name"]` at my server(PHP). But I am developing a web page for iPad which doesn't expose the file system. But later, this will be handled by using phone gap. But now for the demo sake, I want to show that upload works. So, now assume that I have the path to a file. And I have it in my web page like `<img src="path" alt="">`

Can I upload this to my server by any means?

Answer (score 0):

If the image is already online you can easily use PHP's `fopen()` to fetch the file and upload it to your own server. This will work if and only if the remote server hasn't installed certain functionality to block external image access.

See this post to find out how: [How to download an image with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802296/how-to-download-an-image-with-php)

Comment: You are suggesting to fetch the URL from the server?  This won't work if the image in any way requires credentials or if the server sniffs for a specific user agent you don't know about.